To check if a given relation given on a set is symmetric or anti-symmetric or both
Consider a set $A=\{1,2,3\}$
and the binary relation $R=\{(1,1),(2,1),(1,2),(1,3),(3,1),(3,2),(2,3)\}$.
I have to check whether it is symmetric or anti-symmetric.
My attempt:
The above relation $R$ is symmetric because $(2,1) \in R$ and so does $(1,2)$.
Similar reason can be given for the other elements. So, $R$ is symmetric.
For an anti-symmetric relation we have if $(a,b) \in R$ then $(b,a) \in R$ iff $a=b$. This condition is applied on $(1,1) $.
Hence, we can conclude that $R$ is both symmetric and anti-symmetric. Is it correct?
Thanks in advance for the help.

$R$ is not antisymmetric. You showed that $R$ satisfies the condition for $a = b = 1$, but you need to check for all pairs of $a, b \in A$. Note that it is actually not essential to check for elements of the form $a \times a$, since the definition for antisymmetry does not stipulate whether these elements need to be in the relation or not.
Take $a = 1, b = 2$: we have $a \times b \in R$. Here, $a \ne b$, so if $R$ is antisymmetric, it must be that $b \times a = 2 \times 1 \notin R$, which is not true.
But $R$ is symmetric, as you have shown.
